# interpretation of partial derivative in quadratic forms

Tags: partial-derivative, regression, regression-analysis

let us suppose we have following quadratic forms and its corresponding partial derivative with respect of $x_1$
[image]

i have seen following intrpretation

[image]

i really did not understand  one fact : if $\beta_{2}$ is negative , then  line is decreasing,  but it says that y is increasing, what is the reason of this ? also if $\beta_{2}$ is negative ,  and we consider  first three part of original equation, we will get  parabola   with negative first coefficients, therefore  arrows of parabola will be  down, so could you  explain in shortly what is the idea behind of given assumption?

Comment: What does “...” mean in the equation for $y$? The pattern seems to be that the last term should be $\hat{\beta}_k x_1^k$, but that doesn't match the given $\partial y/\partial x_1$. And in any case, $y$ is not a quadratic form, since it contains terms which are not of degree two.

Comment: i have took screenshot from one source, maybe it is not correct

Answer (score 0):

If $\beta_2 < 0$ you have "frown" parabola with respect to $x_1$, namely an increase in one unit in $x_1$ will increase $y$ by $\beta_1 + 2\beta_2x_1$ units until its maximum, while the the rate of increase will gradually slow dawn until the curve reaches its maximum point at $-\frac{\beta_1}{2\beta_2}$. For $x_1 > -\frac{\beta_1}{2\beta_2}$   an increase in $x_1$ will decrease $y$ by $\beta_1 + 2\beta_2x_1$ in an accelerating rate as $x_1$ goes further from its maximum.

The same logic you can apply for $\beta_2 > 0$ while in this case you'll have "smiling" parabola.